# Get a backup of the XML for a an Azure Resource Group

Tags: azure-resource-manager

I can use the powershell command: New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment, with a relevant template file to create an instance of all the items within the template. In fact, this is how I initially created some of the components in the current resource group I am working on. Since creating my Azure components I have tweaked things quite a lot, and I would like to create a template based on the setup in my resource group as it stands now, this would allow me to run the above command and to recreate the components if I ever need to.

Can anyone tell me if there is a way to create a template based on an existing resource group?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there are some MS docs detailing the process here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-export-template